# Capture an image using a camera and then draw a 'freeform' 'filled' area over the captured image using Python, SimpleCV & OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, simplecv

I'm trying to work with Python, opencv and simplecv. I want to capture an image using a camera and then draw a 'freeform' 'filled' area over the captured image using Mouse. Can somebody please help me accomplish this. Here is what I have done till now:

```
from SimpleCV import Camera, Display, Image, Color

cam = Camera()
display = Display()
img = cam.getImage()
img.save(display)

while not display.isDone():
    if display.mouseLeft:
        img.dl().circle((display.mouseX, display.mouseY), 4, Color.WHITE, filled=True)
        img.save(display)
        img.save("draw.png")
```

I can draw over the captured Image, but only with circles. That too are placed far too wide if I draw with normal speed. Here's how it looks:

[image: The drawing done over captured image]

Whereas I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image: This is how I want to draw the area]

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: first show your code and full error message (in question).

Comment: simple example which draw clickable buttons on frame from camera - openCV - https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/cv2/display-button/main.py

Comment: Hi @furas, Thanks for the reply. As I said I've just begun working with SimpleCV, OpenCV and don't know much and still learning. Just simple image capture using the following:

`code`
cam = Camera()
img = cam.getImage()
img.show()
`code`

I dont know how to proceed. Coudn't find anything related to this.

I just want to Capture an Image using a camera. 
Then I want to mark out an area of the captured image by drawing a freeform area filled with any color using mouse.

Comment: check code in link in previous comment.

Comment: @furas : I've updated my post with what I have been able to do till now.

Comment: istead of drawing circles (and save in file) better keep mouse position on list to draw later some polygon (and save all at the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep mouse position on list and draw polygon:

```
from SimpleCV import Camera, Display, Image, Color

cam = Camera()
display = Display()
img = cam.getImage()
img.save(display)

points = []

while not display.isDone():
    if display.mouseLeft:
        point = (display.mouseX, display.mouseY)

        points.append( point )

        if len(points) > 2:
            img.dl().polygon(points, filled=True, color=Color.RED)

        img.dl().circle(point, 4, Color.WHITE, filled=True)

        img.save(display)
        img.save("draw.png")
```

Read SimpleCV doc: [Drawing on Images in SimpleCV](http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/display.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @furas . It is eaxctly what I needed. You are a **Lifesaver**. I am going through the documentation, still miles to go. Regards Max. :)